# Replacing private helper methods with global functions in Python?

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns

In Python there is no real notion of private access. It's merely suggested by social convention with `_` prepended in method names.

```py
class Handler:
    def _timestamp_to_datetime(self, timestamp: int): # <- "private" method
        return time.gmtime(timestamp)

    def handle(self, message):
        time = self.timestamp_to_datetime(message["timestamp"])
        ...
```

Python will still allow outside access to the method, and IDE Intellisense will even support it.

```py
handler = Handler()
handler._timestamp_to_datetime(1620000000) # <- allowed and supported by IDE intellisense
```

[image: Screenshot of VSCode autosuggesting the method]

I've thought about simply moving private methods out of the class and into the top-level scope above.

```py
def timestamp_to_datetime(self, timestamp: int):
    return time.gmtime(timestamp)

class Handler:
    def handle(self, message):
        time = timestamp_to_datetime(message["timestamp"])
        ...
```

This has a couple advantages:

1. Outside callers are not able to access the function, keeping the interface purely public.
2. Internal references to the function are a bit more concise without the `self` keyword.

Given that I usually put class definitions in their own dedicated file, global pollution wouldn't be an issue. All top-level functions in the file `Handler.py` can be assumed to be helper/private methods to the class `Handler`.

**I have three questions:**

1. Are there any arguments against this style, or better alternatives?
2. Is this common in industry/how would professional developers feel about it?
3. Why don't we always do this for private/helper methods that don't rely on `self.` properties, even in languages with real privacy? Classes often have a series of helper methods whose only role serves in transforming data that the public methods return; why even have those directly associated with the class when they could be global utility functions?

Answer (score 1):

Since the instance method doesn't actually *use* `self`, it would be better to define it either as a regular function or a static method. Which you choose is mostly a matter of opinion.

You've already seen how to make it a regular function; here it is as a static method:

```
class Handler:
    @staticmethod
    def _timestamp_to_datetime(timestamp: int):
        return time.gmtime(timestamp)

    def handle(self, message):
        time = self.timestamp_to_datetime(message["timestamp"])
        ...
```

Note that since it does nothing *but* call `time.gmtime`, you could shorten the definition to

```
class Handler:
    _timestamp_to_datetime = staticmethod(time.gmtime)

    def handle(self, message):
        time = self.timestamp_to_datetime(message["timestamp"])
        ...
```

(and similarly for the regular function,

```
timestamp_to_datetime = time.gmtime
```

)